# How to save custome value field in MVC5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I using MVC5 to generate a model with some custom field. I have a field Region each person can Add a record based on his Region.
In my View I added :

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @if (User.IsInRole("RiyadhAdminAssistant"))
                {

                    @:Riyadh

                }
                @if (User.IsInRole("JeddahAdminAssistant"))
                {
                   @:JEDDAH

                }
                @if (User.IsInRole("AlAhsaAdminAssistant"))
                {
                    @*<text><b>AlAhsa</b></text>*@
                    @:AlAhsa

                }


            </div>
        </div>
```

All things appear good to me BUT the values for Region is not stored in the DataBase! how can save it. 
Any Help please

Thanks in advance.

Comment: question not clear to me I guess

Comment: I want to save in the DB "Riyadh" as region if the user is in RiyadhAdminAssistant Role. Its appear in the view but it isn't stored in the DB.

Comment: Why would you render a view for this. You already know the `Region` in the controller so what is the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a form, you need to attach the value to a form element, which can be posted to your server. You need to assign a name, so that you can access the value in your controller and save it in the database:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   @if (User.IsInRole("RiyadhAdminAssistant"))
   {
       <input type="hidden" name="role" value="Riyadh" />
       @:Riyadh
   }
   @if (User.IsInRole("JeddahAdminAssistant"))
   {
       <input type="hidden" name="role" value="JEDDAH" />
       @:JEDDAH
   }
   @if (User.IsInRole("AlAhsaAdminAssistant"))
   {
       <input type="hidden" name="role" value="AlAhsa" />
       @*<text><b>AlAhsa</b></text>*@
       @:AlAhsa
   }
</div>
```

In your controller, in the action associated with the form, you can access the `role` parameter (you can name it whatever you want):

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string role)
{
     //store "role" in the database
}
```

**EDIT:** as already pointed out in the comments, you already know the users's role, therefore you don't need to render additional HTML. Instead, just check the role on the server, before saving the data in the database. This answer is a *proof of concept* and should not be used in specific situations when the data is already known and the browser does not need it.

Comment: You should not render inputs for this. When you post back, check data User.IsInRole(..)` in the controleer and then save the value. Sending extra information to the client and then back again only degrades performance

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I agree. That would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for you to be able to save it on your database you have to store it inside a form and have a submit button to trigger the saving.

```html
model NameSpaceForYourModel

<form action="@Url.Action("SaveAction","RegionController")" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @if (User.IsInRole("RiyadhAdminAssistant"))
                {

                   @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Riyadh)

                }
                @if (User.IsInRole("JeddahAdminAssistant"))
                {
                    @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Jeddah)

                }
                @if (User.IsInRole("AlAhsaAdminAssistant"))
                {
                    @*<text><b>AlAhsa</b></text>*@
                    @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Alahsa)

                }


            </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
```

Comment: should I write like this @:Riyadh , or what should I do?